# replace set_fact to vars in ansible role

Tags: ansible

Have this ansible playbook.
Need change it for role without facts. How can I rewrite this code for variables using in role/default/main.yml

Thank you

```
---

- name: test my group
  hosts: my-group


  tasks:
  - name: test1 fact set
    set_fact:
         var1: 2
         var2: 3
    when: hostname is test1 

  - name: test2 fact set
    set_fact:
         var1: 3
         var2: 3
    when: hostname is test2

  - debug: var="var1 + var2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set host-specific variables you can set them in a file named after the host in the `host_vars` directory adjacent to either your playbook or your inventory.  E.g., given this layout:

```
.
├── host_vars
│   ├── test1.yaml
│   └── test2.yaml
└── roles
    └── myrole
        ├── defaults
        │   └── main.yaml
        └── tasks
            └── main.yaml
```

Then variables defined in `host_vars/test1.yaml` will be set for host `test1`, etc.

Otherwise, the only way to set host-specific variables is using something like a `set_fact` or `include_vars` task along with a `when` conditional like you've shown in your question.

---

If you really need to this in your role's `defaults/main.yaml` file, you could do something like:

```
var1: '{% if inventory_hostname == "test1" %}2{% else %}3{% endif %}'
```

But that's going to be hard to read if the number of variables or number of hosts is large.